# Filtering out abnormal shapes from a binary image in python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, shapes

Any ideas for filters I could use to clean the following image up?
[image]

Perhaps something with a polygonal approximation?

Comment: What does cleaning mean? What is considered abnormal? Explain with more details please!

Comment: As in I have two contours here, one of which corresponds to a gate, and the other is some strange shaped blob.  How might I go about removing the oddly shaped blob on the image in a robust fashion

Comment: Will it always be a gate in your images ?

Comment: Yup!  Same proportions

Comment: But varying size.  Since you could be viewing the gate from several distances and angles

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem. Here is what I did:

1. Small opening to clean the image from all the small useless patterns (not mandatory in your case)
2. Connected component labeling.
3. Separate each component
4. For each component, compute the geodesic diameter ([here is an illustration](http://imagej.net/_images/thumb/2/2f/MorphoLibJ-perimiter-geodesic-diameter-computation.png/400px-MorphoLibJ-perimiter-geodesic-diameter-computation.png), and [here a paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00834415/document)).
5. The pattern with the longest diameter is the one you are looking for.

In your case, if the proportions are always the same, then you can simply keep the biggest component.

Comment: What do you mean geodesic diameter?  Won't that find the biggest component? What if the gate is small / far away and the noise is a large blob?

Comment: I've updated my answer and gave two links for the geodesic diameter. The geodesic diameter will give you the longest pattern, so in your case the door. As I said, if the door is always bigger than the door, then you can filter you image using the size, but if it is not always the case, it does not work.

Comment: One other approach I was looking at was taking the skeleton and then removing closed loops.  Do you know how I might do the loop detection in opencv?

Comment: Also the geodesic diameter still scales with size so I don't see how that would filter large blobs

Comment: The door is a really long shape, when blobs are random, puffy shape. In your example, the geodesic diameter is at least 4 times longer than the blobs.

Comment: The easiest way to find loops is to find holes in the patterns, then the loops are around.

Comment: Is there an easy way to compute the geodesic diameter in OpenCV?

Comment: I don't use OpenCV, so I don't know. But the paper I pointed out uses only distance maps, which should be implemented in OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shape descriptor that is rotation,scale and translation invariant like Hu moments.

Calculate the shape descriptor of the wanted shape from one image that you filtered manually (Form the image above just take the biggest connected component)

For each new image calculate the matchShapes for each one of the connected component and the original Hu moments and take the connected component that got the lowest value(which is the closest shape).